# How to get data from a corresponding column if cell matches data from another sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

[Source Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sf9H.png)
[Filtered Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLWrZ.png)

I have two sheets, one is the Source Sheet and another is the Filtered Sheet. I want to get the corresponding **GROUP ROLL** from **Source Sheet** if the **NUMBER** in the **Filtered Sheet** is also present in the **Source Sheet**.

***For example:*** In the **Filtered Sheet**, the NUMBER *161* is also present in the **Source Sheet**. I want to know how I can get the *DG8* from the Source to the Filtered sheet.

Sorry if the description was too vague.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (not just screenshots), including the formula you currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use VLOOKUP in 'Filterd Sheet'!C2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B; 'Source Sheet'!B:C; 2; 0)))
```

if its based also on names (not just number) use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"♦"&B2:B; 
 {'Source Sheet'!A:A&"♦"&'Source Sheet'!B:B \ 'Source Sheet'!C:C}; 2; 0)))
```

or if you are eng locale:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"♦"&B2:B, 
 {'Source Sheet'!A:A&"♦"&'Source Sheet'!B:B, 'Source Sheet'!C:C}, 2, 0)))
```